# Exception occurs while executing the select statement having the where clause, using the jobs.query API in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Can you help me with this.
I have a below table created in bigquery with all the datatypes.

**Field name       Type      Mode**

ID           NUMERIC     REQUIRED
IsValid      BOOLEAN    NULLABLE
Name          STRING    NULLABLE
Binary         BYTES    NULLABLE
Time            TIME    NULLABLE
JoinDate        DATE    NULLABLE
LastAccess  DATETIME    NULLABLE
LastJoin    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE

Using JAVA API jobs.query, When I try to select the data form this table using the date field in where clause, I get the below error.
*Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: 'JoinDate' is type int32, '2012-05-23' is type string",
    "reason" : "invalidQuery"
  } ],
  "message" : "Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: 'JoinDate' is type int32, '2012-05-23' is type string",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}*

**Below is the java code.**

```
package app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

public class WhereCLause {

    //Create Entry Point: Main function
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String projectId = "projectID";

        // Create a new Bigquery client authorized via Application Credentials.
        Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();
        String query = "Select * from datasetId.AllDataTypes where JoinDate='2012-05-23'";

        System.out.println(query);
        executeQuery(query, bigquery, projectId);
    }

    public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {

        String jsonFilePath="file.json";

        // Create the credential
        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        InputStream credentialStream = new FileInputStream(new File(jsonFilePath));
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialStream, transport, jsonFactory);
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
        }

        return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("BigqueryApplication").build();
    }

    private static void executeQuery(String querySql, Bigquery bigquery, String projectId) throws IOException {
        QueryResponse query = bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, new QueryRequest().setQuery(querySql)).execute();

        System.out.print("\nResults:\n------------\n");

        for (TableRow row : query.getRows()) {
            for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
                System.out.print(field.getV());
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the SQL directly in the BigQuery console?

Comment: Yes, this does not work in the bigquery console. In the bigquery console the below works fine: Select * from exploreTest.AllDataTypes where JoinDate =date('2012-05-23'); But again this does not work from java code

Comment: @shruti_gupta, the error stated that the format between the fields do not match. Although you mentioned that `JoinDate` is `DATE` type in the error it says it is `int64`. So, can you try to cast `'2012-05-23'` to int64/date within your query in your java code and check if it works? It would be as follows: `CAST('2012-05-23' as INT64)` or `DATE '2012-05-23'` . Please, let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreMoraes This does not work either. If I write the query string as : String query = "Select * from exploreTest.AllDataTypes where JoinDate=CAST('2012-05-23' as INT64)"; I get error for INT64.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes If I write the query string as   String query = "Select * from exploreTest.AllDataTypes where JoinDate=DATE '2012-05-23'";
I again get the error as below
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Encountered \" <STRING_LITERAL> \"\\'2012-05-23\\' \"\" at line 1, column 60.\nWas expecting:\n    <EOF>\n[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]",
    "reason" : "invalidQuery"

Comment: @shruti_gupta, what is the error message when you used CAST() ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Select * from exploreTest.AllDataTypes where JoinDate=CAST('2012-05-23' as INT64)
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "1.55 - 1.81: Unrecognized type INT64\n[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]",
    "reason" : "invalidQuery"
  } ]

Comment: I see. Can you also try to use a parameterised query? So you would define the variable before ( including its type) then use it inside the query String. According to the documentation, it should be done like [this](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/#parameterized-queries). So in your where statement you would reference a `DATE` or `INT64`.

Comment: Continuing, the parameters can be int64 or date (BigQueryDbType.Int64 and BigQueryDbType.Date, respectively), [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryDbType.html) . Please, let me know if it worked.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes The API sample that you shared is for .NET. I am looking for a similar solution in Java.